# Get same named columns separately after left join in mysql using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 2 tables one of them stores students and the other one managers

students have **name surname**, 
eventually managers have **name** and **surname** too.

I also store **added_by** in students table to check which manager added the student.

With the query I join tables

```
   $students = \App\Student::with('payment')->with('discontinuities')
                ->leftJoin('managers','students.added_by','=','managers.id')
                ->get();
```

lets say student is

> Name Surname Added_by
>
> Jon Doe        1

and Manager is

> id name surname
>
> 1  jane doe

So when I join those 2 tables with the query I give above. My student becomes

**Jane doe** because of name conflicts in those 2 tables.
Simply manager's name overwrites to student's name since both columns named same.

I could actually join only some columns in managers table however I need this name column to print out **added_by** column with the managers name 
and of course I can change columns name to something else in a table however this would be too much work because I have to refactor each query in my application one by one and also test everything from scratch

so my question is how can I join those 2 tables and prevent conflictions on columns with same name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$students = \App\Student::with('payment')->with('discontinuities')
    ->leftJoin('managers','students.added_by','=','managers.id')
    ->select('students.*','managers.name as m_name','managers.surname as m_s_name','managers.other_column_if_needed','managers.another_column_if_needed')
    ->get();
```

This way your `managers` table's `name` column will be treated as `m_name` and `surname` column will be treated as `m_s_name`

Comment: oh I didn't know that I can change column names after joining them. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue earlier today, the 'get' method takes in an array of the column names which you want in the result as parameter. Therefore to prevent the conflicts you have to give those columns an alias name like so :

```
$students = \App\Student::with('payment')->with('discontinuities')
->Join('managers','students.added_by','=','managers.id')
->get(['students.*', 'managers.name as managers_name', 'managers.surname as managers_surname', 'managers.other_column_if_needed']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Years after... i found this while searching on google.

To make the query take the intial table columns and not the joined one. supposing that the joined table has an alias 't_alias' and the initial table is named 'table_name', add a line after the join with:

```
$builder->addSelect('t_alias.*')->addSelect('table_name.*');
```

This should prevent the override.

Note: switching those instructions will invert the effect if needed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you should specify column names and tables in the `get()` part of your query.

example:

```
$students = \App\Student::with('payment')->with('discontinuities')
    ->leftJoin('managers','students.added_by','=','managers.id')
    ->get(['managers.Name', 'managers.Surname', 'students.name', 'students.surname']);
```